# Exposing WCF subclasses based on an abstract class

Tags: c#, wcf, abstract-class

I have an abstract class which I would like to be able to expose to WCF so that any subclasses will also be able to be started as a WCF service.
This is what I have so far:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "PeopleManager", Namespace = "http://localhost:8001/People")]
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
[DataContract(Namespace="http://localhost:8001/People")]
[KnownType(typeof(Child))]
public abstract class Parent
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "{name}/{description}")]
    public abstract int CreatePerson(string name, string description);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Person/{id}")]
    public abstract Person GetPerson(int id);
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public int CreatePerson(string name, string description){...}
    public Person GetPerson(int id){...}
}
```

When trying to create the service in my code I use this method:

```
public static void RunService()
{
    Type t = typeof(Parent); //or typeof(Child)
    ServiceHost svcHost = new ServiceHost(t, new Uri("http://localhost:8001/People"));
    svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(t, new BasicHttpBinding(), "Basic");
    svcHost.Open();
}
```

When using Parent as the type of service I get
`The contract name 'Parent' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'Parent'.`
OR 
`Service implementation type is an interface or abstract class and no implementation object was provided.`

and when using the Child as the type of service I get
`The service class of type Namespace.Child both defines a ServiceContract and inherits a ServiceContract from type Namespace.Parent. Contract inheritance can only be used among interface types.  If a class is marked with ServiceContractAttribute, then another service class cannot derive from it.`

Is there a way to expose the functions in the Child class so I don't have to specifically add the WCF attributes?

**Edit**
So this

```
[ServiceContract(Name= "WCF_Mate", Namespace="http://localhost:8001/People")]  
    public interface IWcfClass{}  

    public abstract class Parent : IWcfClass {...}  
    public class Child : Parent, IWcfClass {...}
```

with starting the service with Child returns
`The contract type Namespace.Child is not attributed with ServiceContractAttribute.  In order to define a valid contract, the specified type (either contract interface or service class) must be attributed with ServiceContractAttribute.`

Comment: if Parent implements IWcfClass, and Child extends Parent, Child doesn't need to implement IWcfClass as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The service contract is usually an interface, not a class. Place your contract into an interface, have the abstract class implement this interface, and let us know what happens when you use Child to start the service.

Edit: Ok, now you need to modify your RunService method to this below. The contract type if IWcfClass, not Child or Parent.

```
public static void RunService()
{
        Type t = typeof(Child);
        ServiceHost svcHost = new ServiceHost(t, new Uri("http://localhost:8001/People"));
        svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWcfClass), new BasicHttpBinding(), "Basic");
        svcHost.Open();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it still doesn't work, unless I didn't implement it properly.  I added the modifications to the question in an edit so it would be easier to read.

Comment: also the  [OperationContract], and [Web*] attributes need to be in the namespace, not in the parent or child class.